# How to include "origin" into "fromtimestamp" function of "datetime" module

Tags: python, timestamp, python-datetime

I want the program to display time stamp, when seconds are given as input. But the origin year in jupyter notebook starts from **1970-01-01**. I want to make the origin as **1980-01-01**. Can somebody help.

I tried this, but how can i include the origin part to this slice of code:

`datetime.fromtimestamp(500021).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add difference (in seconds) between `01-01-1970` and `01-01-1980` from your timestamp.

You can get it like this:

```
td1 = datetime.strptime("01-01-1970", "%d-%m-%Y")
td2 = datetime.strptime("01-01-1980", "%d-%m-%Y")
print((td2 - td1).total_seconds())
# Output is 315532800.0
```

So after you got it you can define your own function:

```
def from_timestamp(ts):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(ts + 315532800.0).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S")
```

In UTC timezone you will get following outputs:

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(0).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S"))
# 01-01-1970 00:00:00

print(from_timestamp(0))
# 01-01-1980 00:00:00

print(from_timestamp(datetime.now().timestamp()))
# 21-12-2032 01:29:04

print(from_timestamp(500021))
# 06-01-1980 06:53:41
```

Answer (score 0):

By converting the origin date as seconds and adding it will help in this case:

`datetime.fromtimestamp(500021 + datetime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S")`